# Automatically expand semantic accordion content by index

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I want to automatically expand the first item in accordion once its ready. As the from the Semantic UI website, here's the syntax..

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion('behavior', argumentOne, argumentTwo...);
```

- refresh  Refreshes all cached selectors and data
- open (index) Opens accordion content at index
- close others Closes accordion content that are not active
- close (index)    Closes accordion content at index
- toggle (index)   Toggles accordion content at index

But I cant figure out how to work out this sample.
Here's my current code

```
 $(".accordion").accordion(
  {
    exclusive: false
  }
);
```

Comment: If you're trying to figure out how to do this with a `SemanticAccordionComponent` (from `ng-semantic`): `component.accordion.nativeElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.click()`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add "active" class on the first element. This is how they do it on their documents too.

Answer (score 0):

in my project, i have a loop to create accordions. To open a accordion I want in Jquery :

```
var tabs = $("div[data-tab='moduleRights2']");
$(tabs).addClass("active");
```

in Html :

```
<p class="item" data-tab="moduleRights2"></p>
```